# R write.csv outputs weird text when saving Chinese characters

Tags: r, csv

In R, when I save a `data.frame` containing Chinese characters as a csv file, I get weird text.

```
df = data.frame(name = c('老王'))

write.csv(df, 'C:/temp/test_chinese_characters.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

This is what the csv file contains:

```
"name" 
"<U+8001><U+738B>"
```

How to solve the problem and get the right characters back.

```
# R version: 4.1.0

getOption("encoding") 
[1] "native.enc"

Sys.getlocal()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

Comment: You are probably in encoding hell. Is your locale set to Chinese or something else (see `help("Sys.getlocale")`)? Can the text editor, which you use to view the CSV, display Chinese characters (e.g., are the necessary fonts installed correctly)?

Comment: My text editor, Python and everything else works fine with Chinese characters. I get the following with Sys.getlocal() `[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"`

Comment: What does `getOption("encoding")` return? Is utf-8 the native encoding on your system? On my system, I see strange characters if I open the CSV with Excel but it looks fine with Notepad++.

Comment: Also, what is your R version?

Comment: R version: 4.1.0 and the `getOption("encoding")` returns`[1] "native.enc"`. Shall I change it into `utf-8`?  Addtionally, my notepad++ shows the same things no matter which encoding I choose in notepad++.

Comment: I strongly recommend to update R as a first step. There have been changes (improvements) and bug fixes regarding how encoding is handled. (Don't change the option.)

Comment: Unfortunately 4.1.0 is the latest version my corporate software store provides and allows. Maybe I have to wait for the new release coming : )

Comment: It might be useful to search the [NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/NEWS.R-4.2.3.html) file for the keyword "encoding". R 4.1.0 is almost two years old.